# Data Validation on elements in a collection with same property names

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I guess this is a weird question as I have not been able to find any info on this.

I have a class called `TextBoxes` with several properties, something like this:

```
public class TextBoxes
{
    public string Tag{ get; set; }
    public string Text {get; set; }
}
```

In my viewmodel, I add some of them to a collection:

```
...
List<TextBoxes> Controls = new List<TextBoxes>;
...

foreach (var item in somelist)
{
      Controls.Add(new TextBoxes(){ Tag=item.tag, Text=""});
      ...
}
```

And finally, in my View I use a `DataTemplate` to add all this controls to my `UserControl`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type clases:TextBoxes}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Label Content="{Binding Tag}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" MinWidth="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0">
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

 ...

 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Controls}">
          <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  </ItemsControl>
```

So far so good, this code shows a bunch of TextBoxes with labels, no problem here.

The problem is when I try to add validation to the property `Text` of each object. As property name is the same in each of them, when I validate the rules and try to get the error message, this contains the error for all of them so I can't show the specific one of each of them.

I use a [helper](https://github.com/pglazkov/MvvmValidation) for validating data. I'll show an example of how I define a rule:

```
foreach (var item in somelist)
{
      Validator.AddRule(() => item.Text, (
                  () => RuleResult.Assert(int.TryParse(item.Text, out o), "Error in " + item.Tag)));
```

As you see, in the rule i set the property to `item.Text`. As this name is the same for all of them, when displaying the errors for each TextBox shows the errors in all of them.

I hope I made myself clear, and that anyone can shed any light here.

Comment: Each `TextBoxes` object is supposed to have its own `Validator`: `item.Validator.AddRule(...)`.

Comment: @mm8 thanks for your comment!. Let me try it. I'm not sure that I like to move the validator to the class, but if it works... I'll update if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `TextBoxes` object is supposed to have its own `Validator`. You would then call `AddRule` of this one for each item:

```
foreach (var item in somelist)
    item.Validator.AddRule(...);
```